Project Manpower Optimization Problem
I have a complex optimization problem that I can't seem to solve. The problem involves optimizing manpower and their scheduling.

There are 10 projects all starting on same date
Each project has 5 tasks to be done (A-E). A to D tasks are sequential and cant be done without ending earlier task. Task E is parallel and can be done anytime. I know the amount of labor-days needed for each task X project.
Each task has specialized labor. So, a labor for A can't do B. Each labor has a cost of 25K units per month. Assume all the projects were received on first day of the first month of the year.

Follwing is the data format with dummy labor-days numbers:

I tried using excel solver to optimize this using below table:

Decision Variable: Number of people, Constraint: # People should be Integer; End Time should be within days complete in (Final column). Unfortunately, Excel doesnt find any solution to this problem and stays at the incumbent solution only. Also, this method doesnt account for reallocation of labor to reduce cost.
Would be really helpful if someone could help with the problem as I am out of my depth.

Your problem setting looks similar to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job-shop_scheduling, which is also a more likely source of solving algorithms for your case

You need to be more explicit about the decision variables.  Do you want to decide how many people to work on project $p$ and task $t$ in month $m$?  Also, you have both months and days in the description, so do you maybe instead want a daily schedule?
